# AC 230 V dimmer for Raspberry PI?

Tags: home-automation

Could anyone recommend an 230 V dimmer for Raspberry PI to control lights? (controllable via e.g. via USB or RS-232)

**UPDATE:** I currently use FadeCandy with server for Raspberry PI to dim leds. I am searching for something to dim 230 V lights, which has support for Raspberry PI.

(It is just for home light dimming - DMX seems to be a bit overkill. And I prefer not to solder it myself, since it may cause fire if I would not solder it properly.)

Comment: If it is off-topic could some please migrate the question to a proper StackExchange site?

Answer (score 3):

As a stage light technician, I would recommand to search about DMX512.

DMX512 is the light control standard protocol, working on XLR cables (3 pins or 5 pins). The point is, it is really easy to find [DMX controlled dimmers](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=dmx%20dimmer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=j8GOVMvZLIuDVLv3gLgF).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer, but the link is not there. Could you please update your answer.

Comment: Well, it's a simple google search about dmx dimmer. So google give you some reseller near you.

Comment: Ok, for simple home dimming it seems to be a bit overkill:)

Comment: A bit overkill, but pretty simple : dmx dimmer is about 50$,, the dmx cable might be very short, a estone usb to dmx adapter is about 20$. And the whole is just plug-and-play, and is year long field tested.

Answer (score 2):

[This may give you some ideas.](https://en.maxchan.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Illumata-HVFE.pdf) Use `MOC3023` (random phase optocoupler) in place of `MOC3043` (zero crossing optocoupler, same pinout) in this schematic.

The ATtiny85 is programmed to receive commands from the Pi over UART and change the phase of the pulse firing accordingly.

I used optical transmission so no optocoupler is used. If you use copper cables you should add optocouplers to the serial line.

My board used a 4A TRIAC derated to 1.5A due to lack of heatsink. Choose your TRIAC according to your ratings.

Comment: +1 Thank you for sharing your solution. I am searching for "a boxed solution" which I could just connect, without having a big fear that it may cause fire (if I do not solder it properly).

Comment: I designed my board following better safety standards than UL and CE and it is still safely dimming my 10W LED lamp for several months now.

Comment: I have updated my question. (I do not consider your design dangerous.)